# Term for sublist of all elements except last?

Tags: list, terminology

The sublist, containing all elements, except first is called "tail".

What is the name of sublist of all elements, except first?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Without context, tail is the end of a list. Head is the beginning of a list. Your clarification of "all except the first" must depend on the environment in which you are working. Tail can refer to any number of elements at the end of a list.